# Mix of Preemptible and Non-preemptible VM instances in Google Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine

I am fairly new to GCP, I have been using AWS previously and I am testing out GCP for some of my projects.

AWS Autoscaling groups had a nifty little feature where you could specify a split of Spot/On-demand instances in the autoscaling group, and more importantly a feature to have *base on-demand instances*, which is something I am looking for in GCP.

I've been going through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible) and googling in general how to achieve this, but I haven't really found concrete answers on how to do it, or if it can even be done. The instance template just has a binary option of selecting yes or no.

I would want at least a few non-preemptive instances in the MIG, as I never want my service to be completely out. So what happens if there's a shortage of non-preemptive instances? Are higher cost non-preemptive instances added to the group to make sure that the MIG still has enough capacity to serve requests? Or does my MIG just run out of instances and my service goes down?

Can someone help me out, or even point me to some resources that will help with this situation?

Comment: Create two Instance Templates and two MIGs, one for each type of instance.

Comment: @JohnHanley that was my initial idea, but i didn't find any traffic flow options on the load balancer settings. How do I control my traffic to goto the non-preemptive MIG in case the preemptive MIG doesn't have any instances. Wouldn't I lose out on half of the traffic?

Comment: If a MIG was not healthy, traffic would flow to the other MIGs. You can manage this using autoscaling policies and health checks.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, you can create two MIGs (one standard and one preemptible) and a Load Balancer.
Then, apply [Health Checks](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts) that will monitor these groups. If preemptible instance group is exhausted, it will fail health check and requests will be only sent to the other group.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this?
[Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/cutting-costs-with-google-kubernetes-engine-using-the-cluster-autoscaler-and-preemptible-vms)

You have to make 2 node-pool, the first one is a static pool that uses a non-preemptive instance without the autoscaling feature, 2nd is a dynamic pool that uses a preemptive instance with the autoscaling feature.

And then you configure node affinity on your service which may look like this:

```
affinity:
nodeAffinity: 
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
    nodeSelectorTerms:
    - matchExpressions:
      - key: cloud.google.com/gke-preemptible
        operator: DoesNotExist
```

Personally, I use the static pool for my supporting services like vault and linkerd. Or maybe some core deployment (you have to separately deploy to both static pool & dynamic pool).

Comment: So I wasn't looking into using kubernetes just yet, as it was just a pretty simple service and an autoscaling group in AWS served my just fine without making things complicated. I just wanted to know if there was something similar in MIGs before actually diving into GKE.